# EDI file generation using SMOOKS

Tags: java, xml, edi, smooks

How can I convert XML file to EDI file using SMOOKS?

I am able to convert EDI to XML, in fact this is part of examples provided by SMOOKS.

Comment: The Smooks framework is no longer under active development - but if have restrictions of using old code - the source github has always had the example to convert EDI to XML->
https://github.com/smooks/smooks/tree/master/smooks-examples/edi-to-xml

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question i tried to do some research on it . Please check if it helps you .

**So here's the source edi file that is to be transformed:**

```
HDR*1*0*59.97*64.92*4.95*Wed Nov 15 13:45:28 EST 2006
CUS*user1*Harry^Fletcher*SD
ORD*1*1*364*The 40-Year-Old Virgin*29.98
ORD*2*1*299*Pulp Fiction*29.99
```

**And this is the expected result of our transformation:**

```
<Order>
    <header>
            <order-id>1</order-id>
            <status-code>0</status-code>
            <net-amount>59.97</net-amount>
            <total-amount>64.92</total-amount>
            <tax>4.95</tax>
            <date>Wed Nov 15 13:45:28 EST 2006</date>
    </header>
    <customer-details>
            <username>user1</username>
            <name>
                    <firstname>Harry</firstname>
                    <lastname>Fletcher</lastname>
            </name>
            <state>SD</state>
    </customer-details>
    <order-item>
            <position>1</position>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <product-id>364</product-id>
            <title>The 40-Year-Old Virgin</title>
            <price>29.98</price>
    </order-item>
    <order-item>
            <position>2</position>
            <quantity>1</quantity>
            <product-id>299</product-id>
            <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
            <price>29.99</price>
    </order-item>
</Order>
```

**The Smooks Configuration**

We simply specify the SmooksEDIParser  as the stream parser. More transformation configurations could be added to transform this message further.
Here's the configuration ("smooks-config.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                  xmlns:edi="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/edi-1.1.xsd">

<!--
Configure the EDI Reader to process the message stream into a stream of SAX events.
-->
<edi:reader mappingModel="/example/edi-to-xml-order-mapping.xml" />

</smooks-resource-list>
```

**Here's the edi mapping** ("/src/main/java/example/edi-to-xml-order-mapping.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<medi:edimap xmlns:medi="http://www.milyn.org/schema/edi-message-mapping-1.0.xsd">
<medi:description name="DVD Order" version="1.0" />
<medi:delimiters segment="&#10;" field="*" component="^" sub-component="~" />
<medi:segments xmltag="Order">
    <medi:segment segcode="HDR" xmltag="header">
        <medi:field xmltag="order-id" />
        <medi:field xmltag="status-code" />
        <medi:field xmltag="net-amount" />
        <medi:field xmltag="total-amount" />
        <medi:field xmltag="tax" />
        <medi:field xmltag="date" />
    </medi:segment>
    <medi:segment segcode="CUS" xmltag="customer-details">
        <medi:field xmltag="username" />
        <medi:field xmltag="name">
            <medi:component xmltag="firstname" />
            <medi:component xmltag="lastname" />
        </medi:field>
        <medi:field xmltag="state" />
    </medi:segment>
    <medi:segment segcode="ORD" xmltag="order-item" maxOccurs="-1">
        <medi:field xmltag="position" />
        <medi:field xmltag="quantity" />
        <medi:field xmltag="product-id" />
        <medi:field xmltag="title" />
        <medi:field xmltag="price" />
    </medi:segment>
</medi:segments>
</medi:edimap>
```

**Executing The Transformation:**

```
// Instantiate Smooks with the config...
Smooks smooks = new Smooks("smooks-config.xml");

try {
// Filter the input message to the outputWriter...
smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource(messageIn), new
StreamResult(messageOut));
} finally {
smooks.close();
}
```

Comment: This example you explained here will create XML file from edi file. But question has been asked about to prepare EDI file from XML data.Can you please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: @RCS Are you able to prepare EDI file from XML data?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the context how i had fixed it couple of years back.

Comment: @RCS are you able to solve this in java